# Tag friends to Facebook post + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, tags

I want to share post on users wall and tag Friends to that post

Like,

Hello All  with Krish.

I am trying to check taggable_Friends api but I am not getting in current Facebook App.

I am using asp.net for this. Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#taggable-friends-4-4

> All endpoints for the Taggable Friends API will now return an empty
>   data set:
>
> ```
> /user/taggable_friends edge
> /user-taggable-friend node
> ```
>
> These endpoints will be deprecated in the near future.

Also, `publish_actions` is deprecated too, so sharing on user walls is not possible with the API anymore.

Comment: Thanks for response, Is there any other way to share on wall with mentioning friends

Comment: no, there is no way. what´s the use case for this anyway?